# show numbers there are not in a column in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a formfield where I can put in numbers in the value between 1 - 10. The numbers are saved in MySQL database. I am looking how to make a query that can return numbers in my database, that has not been put in through my formfield.

Fx: If the following number has been put in:
[1,4,8,9,10]
Then I have a div tag there is printing those numbers out.

That means that the following numbers need to printet in another div tag is:
[2,3,5,6,7]

But I am quite in doubt how to do that, because those numbers does not exist in my database yet, because the number has not been put in yet.

UPDATE:

If there has been typed in 1000 numbers between 1 - 10, all numbers are of course registred. But the query should work so the 5 numbers that have been registered the fewest times is showing up.

I have tried this, but it is of course not working. But maybe I can use it for a start?:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT numbers FROM numbertable GROUP BY numbers ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC LIMIT 10;");
```

Best Regards
Mads

Comment: hard to say how you're storing those in db in the first place. As seperate rows? as `1,2,3,4,5`?

Comment: see the answer below. Kind of what I also had in mind. ask them now.

Comment: Ist of all put them in db than select them... make an array like 1, 2,,, 10 and chk if value exist in array store them else not exist store db value u will get the two arrays

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I just tried to update my question. The main problem for me, is how I also take the fewest numbers out, if there was put in fx 1000 numbers in the range of 1 - 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
Select numbers from yourTable where numbers NOT IN (2,3,5,6,7)
```

That's the basic idea of how the syntax works.  However you want to build that "not in" list, is up to you.